# jQuery find - What order does it return elements in?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been using jQuery's `find` method and it's been very useful.

However, I came across an example where the `find` seemed to be duplicating things and not returning elements in the order they appeared in the document. (I'm not sure if find is supposed to do this - I doubt it).

However, it shouldn't have duplicates in the elements it finds and show the wrong order, surely?

Full example can be found here: [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/EMzDn/3) - Notice how span[9] and span[10] are in the wrong order and duplicated.

Why is this the case?

### Update

Updated so that output is written to document, please use new link above.

Comment: what browser and version are you using? in no occurrence I have span 10 before 9 (chrome 17)

Comment: I am trying it on Firefox 3.6 and Chrome 17. So order doesn't hold true for you too? Are things duplicated too?

Comment: It's easier to read if you put your JavaScript in the JavaScript frame: http://jsfiddle.net/EMzDn/10/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`.find()` returns elements in document order. More info here: http://docs.jquery.com/Release%3ajQuery_1.3.2

I think the anomaly has something to do with the wildcard selectors. Are those necessary? Removing them seems to resolve the issue.

Comment: Very interesting! I removed the second wild card `*` as I need the first and it seems to be working - why would this have such an effect?!

Comment: @Abs: If you read the documentation, you'll understand that `*=` means *attribute contains*. Clearly `w_line_1` and `w_line_10` both contain the string `"w_line_1"`.

Answer (score 0):

you add unused * in your code, replace this find with your code:

```
$('#div1').find("*[class=w_line_" + i + "]").each(function () {
```

and have this, have good time;

Answer (score 0):

I can´t find anything strange with the order.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
        console.log(i);
        $('#div1').find("*[class*=w_line_" + i + "]").each(function() {
            console.log(i, $(this));
        });
    }

});
```

This selector seems to return the elements in the same order as yours and I can´t see any duplicates.

```
$('#div1 *[class*=w_line_' + i + ']')
```