# How to get elements sorted in a way that reflects their position in the document

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a sortable list in a web application, and i would like to update the model when the user ends his interaction.

In order to do that, i need to get an array of elements, with positions in the array reflecting their positions in the document. With that i can iterate the array and update the model position for each element.

The question is, can i rely on jQuery `find` to give me the ordered children of an element?

If yes, where is this stated in the jQuery doc?

If not, what is a simple and reliable way to get the elements in their order?

Comment: jQuery `.find()` returns elements in document order, have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8771463/jquery-find-what-order-does-it-return-elements-in

Comment: thanks, if you add a link to the jQuery relevant doc, this could be the valid answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery `.find()` returns the elements in document order, this change took effect in version 1.3.2. This is mentioned here - http://blog.jquery.com/2009/02/20/jquery-1-3-2-released/

If you search on the jQuery website for "document order" there is documentation regarding other methods which also return elements this way, or have been updated to return elements in document order, as this is probably the preferred way of receiving the array for most people.

Answer (score 0):

There is an event in sortable (SORT) which fires when you stop the interaction. What you can do is assign an data-position and apply the index position of it as a value of data-position using index() function. Later you can find out the changed position of the elements by comparing the order of elements using its index value.